# Smallest value in an array

Tags: java

I have to find the smallest value in an array and print it, I have the code but I can't connect it with my runner file, its telling me "go(int[]) in RaySmallest cannot be applied to (int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" for all of my 12 samples.

```
public class RaySmallest
{
 public static int go(int[] ray)
 {
   {
        int[] numbers = {};
     int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i =0;i<numbers.length;i++) 
        {
        if(smallest > numbers[i]) 
        {
            smallest = numbers[i];
        }
        }
    System.out.println("Smallest number in array is : " +smallest);
    }
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Thats my runner file

```
public class SmallestRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {
  RaySmallest.go(-88,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,90,10,5);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,-99); 
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(10,20,30,40,50,-11818,40,30,20,10);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(65478);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(578,578);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(6,13,-98,100,-987,7);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(9,9,9,13,567);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(-222,1,5,6,9,12,29,1);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,-2,6);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(12,15,18,21,23,1000);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(250,19,17,15,13,11,10,9,6,3,2,1,0);
  System.out.println();

  RaySmallest.go(9,10,-8,10000,-5000,-3000);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You have declared your method to take 1 argument, yet you are passing it 12.

Comment: Numbers is also null so as soon as you fix that you'll get a null pointer error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method expects an `int[]` as a parameter: `int go(int[] ray)`. An easy way to pass it would be to do this:

```
RaySmallest.go(new int[] {6, 13, -98, 100, -987, 7});
```

Alternatively, you can define the `go` method in such a way that it expects *multiple parameters*, like this:

```
int go(int... ray)
```

Now you can call it as you were doing before, without problems:

```
RaySmallest.go(6, 13, -98, 100, -987, 7);
```

Also, there's another bug in your code: the `go()` method is *not* using the `ray` parameter, instead it's traversing the `numbers` array, which is empty. For a quick fix, do this:

```
int[] numbers = ray;
```

Comment: This works but it prints out     2147483647 every time

Comment: @AnonDog that's a different problem. In your code, you're iterating over the `numbers` array (which is empty!) instead of traversing the `ray` parameter. For a quick fix, do this: `int[] numbers = ray;`

Comment: Replace the line where you defined it with the one I suggest. Or alternatively, delete it and rename all occurrences of `numbers` to use `ray` instead.